# List for TI-84 z80 assembly calls?

Tags: assembly, texas-instruments, z80

I am searching for a list of all assembler functions/calls, but seem to be unable to find any for the TI-84 or TI-83 (their assembler code is nearly the same).
Additionally, I could neither find a list of the standard functions of TI-Basic for z80 Assembler code.
Does anyone knows where I can find such lists?
While the z80 assembly instructions can be found, the specific differences for the calculators are rather hard to find.

Comment: There are loads of links in the Wiki article on TI-83. One of them is [Cemetech](https://www.cemetech.net/resources/).

Answer (score 5):

From everything I can find online about it, TI never released any official documentation for their ROM or their memory map. There has been a reverse engineering effort made to document the ti 83 and 84 roms to extract the functions [here](http://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=Calculator_Documentation#TI-84_Plus_CE.5B-T.5D.2C_TI-83_Premium_CE).

For the ti83 plus at least they provide an include file with the addresses to certain functions in the rom ([here](http://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=83Plus:OS:ti83plus.inc))

The documentation is not complete for all functions, but it is a pretty exhaustive list and also has information about the mmio registers that you can use to control things like the serial port and the display hardware

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [basic TI-84 manual](https://education.ti.com/download/en/ed-tech/C4D11EB6D86B47D19CD768E54A967441/6CC4C5AED5004F808892046AD33D4A35/TI84Plus_guidebook_EN.pdf), there were two PDFs released by Texas Instruments that may be useful for programming in assembly:

- [TI-83 Plus Developer Guide](https://education.ti.com/download/en/ed-tech/830D08FF31804AEAA2F03B8F5E89AD14/672891A1E98349CAB91C11B4928C253C/sdk83pguide.pdf)
- [TI-83 Plus System Routines](https://education.ti.com/download/en/ed-tech/830D08FF31804AEAA2F03B8F5E89AD14/01E6AF2CADF84171B6F2E2039357BAAC/83psysroutines.pdf)

The latter one is quite a thorough reference of all the system calls that can be made via assembly.

The above is for the TI-83, but the TI-84 is almost identical and only added a handful of extra functions which I think are listed [here](https://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=83Plus:Basic:New_Tokens_on_the_84_Plus#ExecLib).

There is also a lot of information online, spread across multiple sites such [Z80 Heaven](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/system:tutorials), [wiki.brandonw.net](http://wiki.brandonw.net), and others.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the "include files" with the symbolic names and corresponding ROM addresses (when the correct page is loaded). Ticalc.org has the commonly-used versions.
Since Texas Instruments never published the official documentation, these are unofficial, and various versions exist from programmers disassembling the ROM and discovering and naming functions themselves.

[TI-83 Include Files](https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/1/156.html)
[TI-84 plus Include Files](https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/243/24319.html)